# How do I use QTikZ on a standalone file

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, tools

My file is quite simple, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but QTikZ barfs on it, saying,

```
[LaTeX] Line 1: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
[LaTeX] Line 1: 
[LaTeX] Line 1: See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.         ...                                                                                                
l.-6     \documentclass
                  {article} 
[LaTeX] Line 1:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF f
```

Is there way to make QTikZ take standalone pictures and remove the preamble?

===

To clarify, I would like to interactively edit the file with QTikZ, and then when it is ready, run it through `pdflatex`. Later on, I would like to make fine tuning again with QTikZ, and then recompile the file.

It is quite a nuisance to remove the preamble each time I go into QTikZ, and it is equally annoying to maintain two files, one with the preamble and the other one included in it, which has the actual figure.

Is there a better way?

Comment: So what you want is to produce a PDF with landscape layout and that picture inside?

Comment: You only need tikz environment on QTikZ

Comment: I will edit the question to make my purpose clearer.

Comment: What about using `tikzedt`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your file `mydocument.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \input{tikzpicture.tex}
\end{document}
```

File `tikzpicture.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then edit `tikzpicture.tex` with `QTikZ`. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I guess this is the best possible, managing two distinct files.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slight variant, that helps a bit in managing file names:

**Main file:** (with `.tex` extension)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \input{\currfilebase.tikz}
\end{document}
```

**TikZ File:**
(with `.tikz` extension)

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With this variation, the base file name is the same: `.tex` file is processed by `pdlfatex` while the `.tikz` file is processed by the `QTikZ`

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe that the question has not been answered completely, I propose another solution. This solution allows to only use one file that also contains a preamble.

Since Yossil Gil wants to use his own preamble, the solution is to adjust the used template accordingly. In the qtikz GUI, just above the editor, you see the template file that is used. The standard behavior (can be changed in Settings -> Templates -> Replace text) is that any occurrence of `<>` is replaced by what you type in the qtikz editor. Therefore, if you create an empty template file just containing `<>`, you will be able to paste your own preamble in the qtikz editor.

Comment: The issue is to only edit the tikz picture while having the preamble of the main document and not doing this each time manually.

Comment: I understand it differently, since Yossi Gil wants to have the preamble insided qtikz and nobody gave an answer how to do that. So let's wait for him to answer.